# Does sp_recompile performance enhancement always link to parameter sniffing?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, parameter-sniffing

We have a production app which runs ok normally, but gave us very poor performance this week. As it was very urgent, I identified the problematic procedure and ran `sp_recompile` against it (forgot to take the plan first).

After running `sp_recompile`, the system became fast again. For me, this indicates a parameter sniffing issue. However, as I forgot to take a plan first, hard to be 100% sure. Could there be other explanations that `sp_recompile` speeds up the performance dramatically?

We use Azure SQL read only replica.

Answer (score 0):

**It's probably parameter sniffing**, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-recompile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) for sp_recompile does note that performance can drop for other reasons as well:

> The queries used by stored procedures, or triggers, and user-defined functions are optimized only when they are compiled. As indexes or other changes that affect statistics are made to the database, compiled stored procedures, triggers, and user-defined functions may lose efficiency. By recompiling stored procedures and triggers that act on a table, you can reoptimize the queries.

That is not to say that some of the above things won't trigger an automatic recompile, however. In fact, most of those *should* trigger a recompile, which is why I wouldn't spend too much time looking down that road.

Depending on your version, enabling [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15) might make it easier to track regressions without having to manually capture plans.

Without the query plans, the stored procedure itself, etc. I would default to assuming parameter sniffing in this case until it happens again. I don't believe there is much more to talk about without more details.

Comment: thanks, we use azure sql read only replica, query store unfortunately doesn't work there.

Comment: I wonder if that doc statement is old. To my knowledge, those things should cause a recompile. Perhaps MS left is there in case they forgot to trigger recompile for some of these operations?

Comment: @daxu if you are satisfied with my answer, you can accept it. Otherwise I recommend adding more details as to what you want out of an answer so that others can work on something more complete for you.